# Individual class Attribute visibility using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have `<li>`s hide and show based on their class names (most of which are multiple classes) selected by the user using a checkbox selector for individual attributes.   I have noticed however that in my implementation, it looks for the attribute, and performs the task, regardless of all of the other attribute selectors on the form. How can I adjust the code so that it shows the `<li>`s based on visibility selections of the individual class attributes?

[Here is the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chrisfrisina/fZmXH/).

As you can see, if you check the 'A' box, it hides 'A', 'AB', 'AC', and 'ABC'.   However the user thinks that any `<li>` with attributes 'B' and 'C' are visible, and 'AB', 'AC', and 'ABC' are hidden.

So if the user selects 'A' to be hidden, then the only `<li>` to be hidden is

'A'

, since it is the only one with just 'A', and 'B' and 'C' are attributes the user wants to be visible, leaving the following visible:

'B', 'C', 'AB', 'AC', 'BC', "ABC'

.   If the user selects 'A' and 'B' to hide, then the following would be hidden:

'A', 'B', 'AB'

; and visible would be:

'C', 'AC', 'BC', and 'ABC'

, since they have a 'C' class attribute.
I'm assuming I would have to make an array or something similar, and then look for any attributes within the array, and display/hide them accordingly.

Comment: The fiddle is missing the JavaScript code.

Comment: try now, sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with a bit less code:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/vnjHn/1/

```
$('form input').on('change', function() {

    var notSelectedList = $('form input:not(:checked)').map(function() {
        return '.' + $(this).attr('name');
    }).get().join(',');

    $('.viewing li').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).is(notSelectedList));
    });

});​
```

It works by building up a comma separated list of the classes which are not to be hidden, an then checks all the list items for any of these classes - which is a slightly easier way of doing the check I think.

Answer (score 0):

building on top of your example here is the code:

```
<form class="form">
    <p> Check to hide </p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1" class="selector"/><label for="1">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2" class="selector"/><label for="2">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3" class="selector"/><label for="3">C</label>
</form><br>

<div class="viewing">
    <ul>
        <li class="1">A</li>
        <li class="2">B</li>
        <li class="3">C</li>
        <li class="1 2">AB</li>
        <li class="2 3">BC</li>
        <li class="1 3">AC</li>
        <li class="1 2 3">ABC</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

and the js:

```
var classes = {'1':false,'2':false,'3':false};
$('form input').on('change', function() {
var itemClass= $(this).attr('name');
console.log(itemClass);
classes[itemClass] = $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked';    
    $('.viewing>ul>li').each(function(){
        var classList =$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
        var hide = true;
        $.each( classList, function(index, item){
            if (classes[item] == false) {
hide = false;                

            };
});
        if(hide == true)
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    });
});​
```

you can find the [demo here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fZmXH/10/)